# How to create a SCSS object that contains multiple font families as properties

Tags: sass

I'm experimenting with the idea of storing font families as properities to a single object in SCSS.  If I have the following items in my .scss file...

```py
$font-fam-mon: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
$font-fam-open: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
$font-fam-rob: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
```

is there any way that we can build an official scss object similar to this concept...

```py
$gfonts: (
"mon" : 'Montserrat', sans-serif,
"open": 'Open Sans', sans-serif,
"rob" : 'Roboto', sans-serif
)
```

and reference it like so...

```css
$gfonts.mon //where needed
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution would be to create a **function**.
The syntax will slightly differ from what you're looking for.
Instead of `$gfonts.mon` you'll be using `font(mon)`

**The code:**

```
@use 'sass:map';
@use 'sass:string';

$gfonts: (
    "mon" : "'Montserrat', sans-serif",
    "open": "'Open Sans', sans-serif",
    "rob" : "'Roboto', sans-serif"
);

@function font($font) {
  @return string.unquote(map.get($gfonts, $font));
}

p {
    font-family: font(open);
}
```

The function taks one parameter: `$font`. It will look in your map `$gfonts` for the key `$font` and return it's value.

**The output:**

```
p {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
```